# Laravel 404 Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with "404 | Not found". The route exists, but I still have the problem.

I've already tried with:

```
php artisan route:list
```

and the route really exists.

**web.php:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::get('/p/{post}', 'PostsController@show'); 
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');

Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');
Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit', 'ProfilesController@edit')->name('profile.edit'); //this shows the form of edit profile
Route::patch('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@update')->name('profile.update'); //this will actually do the process of updating our profile
```

**ProfilesController.php:**

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    return view('profiles.edit', compact('user'));
}

public function update(User $user){ //some validation
        $data =request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'url' => 'url', //require the http://
            'image' => '',
        ]);

        auth()->user()->profile->update($data); //auth() is a protection. Without this, an external user, for example in incognite, can edit the profile
    }
```

**edit.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<form action="/profile->{{ $user->id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH') <!--it's not permitted write method = 'patch', by default it will be get-->
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-2">

                        <div class="row">
                            <h2>Edit Profile</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="title" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Title</label>
                                    <input id="title"
                                           type="text" 
                                           class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror"  
                                           name="title"
                                           value="{{ old('title') ?? $user->profile->title }}" 
                                           autocomplete="title" autofocus>

                                    @error('title')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                            </div>
```

**index.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 p-5">
            <img src="https://scontent-fco1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/1ba68a1705bb9cdd1f7f2ea9ea062810/5D79BFC8/t51.2885-19/s320x320/22709172_932712323559405_7810049005848625152_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-fco1-1.cdninstagram.com" style = "height:150px" class = "rounded-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 pt-5">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
                <h1>{{ $user -> username}}</h1>
                <a href="/p/create">Add New Post</a>
            </div>
            <a href="/profile/{{ $user->id }}/edit">Edit Profile</a>
            <div class = "d-flex">
            <div class = "pr-5"><strong>{{ $user->posts->count() }}</strong> posts</div>
                <div class = "pr-5"><strong>23k</strong> followers</div>
                <div class = "pr-5"><strong>212</strong> following</div>
            </div>  
        <div class = "pt-4 font-weight-bold">{{ $user->profile->title }}</div> 
        <div>{{ $user->profile->description }}</div> 
        <div><a href="#">{{ $user->profile->url }}</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-5">
        @foreach($user->posts as $post)
            <div class="col-4 pb-4">
            <a href="/p/{{ $post->id }}">
                <img src="/storage/{{ $post->image }}" class = "w-100">
            </a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The error is only "404 | Not Found". When I click the button for edit the address became: "http://localhost:8000/profile->1" and the error is probably there.

Comment: The problem is probably in the way you're generating the link in the view

Comment: It's a view issue - what's in the blade file?

Comment: @apokryfos yes, I agree.

Comment: @Trent I have two blade file: edit.blade.php and index.blade.php Now I'm editin the post with the code of edit.blade.php, ok?

Comment: It's the index we probably want.

Comment: Run `php artisan optimize:clear`, I think it is a cache issue.

Comment: @eamirgh i ran that command, without any result.

Comment: @Trent ok, i'm editing with the code of index

Comment: Do you have a "index" method in your ProfilesController.php file?

Comment: @eamirgh yes, I have, do you want the code?

Comment: Sorry about asking this but what is the exact url getting 404?
is that  "http://localhost:8000/profile->1" or "http://localhost:8000/profile/1"?

Comment: Can you check rewrite module? Is it enabled?

Comment: @eamirgh the error is on "localhost:8000/profile->1"

Comment: @Pheara I don't know. What is it?

Comment: It's an apache module to enable url to be rewritten. What is your server environment? Are you using windows, linux or mac?

Comment: I'm using mac. I'm following a tutorial, and i think the code is the same @Pheara

Comment: Can you check /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and find this line `LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so` If it's commented, uncomment it.

Comment: @Pheara yes, it's commented. I uncomment it. But what is the aim of this action?

Comment: can you post the show method from the ProfileController please

Comment: action="/profile->{{ $user->id }}" , atleast this seems to be the first issue

Answer (score 4):

Fistly the issue is you're generating an invalid URL.

`/profile->{{ $user->id }}` will generate `/profile->1` but `->` must not be part of the URL. Normally you could fix this by just doing `/profile/{{ $user->id }}`.

However I suggest you should use Laravel's URL generator helpers to generate URLs.

For example: `<form action="/profile->{{ $user->id }}"` should be:

```php
<form action="{{ route('profile.update', [ 'user' => $user->id ])}}"
```

As a reminder there's 3 major route helpers:

```
url('/relative/path'); // Will generate an absolute URL to your app based on a relative URL
action('Controller@action'); // Will generate a URL which calls the specified controller 
route('route.name'); // Will generate a URL based on the named route
```

The second parameter in `route` will fill in required route parameters.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that ->

Comment: At this point when I click the button for updating the profile, i get a blank page. I have to click on the button of recharge page for get "localhost:8000/profile/1" Do you know why?

Comment: @CasellaJr I think i used the wrong route name (`profile.edit` instead of `profile.update`). Try the update

Comment: No, i changed only profile-> into profile/ because the I've never used the second method. In future I will try that. But in this case I don't know why i have to refresh the page

Comment: Your `update` method does seem to update but doesn't provide any feedback to the user. Typically you'd put a `return redirect()->to('/profile/'.$user->id);` at the end of that method to redirect back to the edit page.

Comment: Ok, thank you very mutch. I have deleted that string before, trying to resolve the main error of the post. And then i've forgotten tu rewrite that string. Thanks. Bye

Comment: @CasellaJr - Seems like this answer solved your problem - consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the url you are trying to reach!
according  to your routes web.php you should visit "http://localhost:8000/profile/1".

Comment: Yes, I think so too. But how I can visit that address and also update?

Comment: @CasellaJr Follow apokryfos's answer, It a more complete answer.

Comment: Yes, i see it. Thank you. I commented on his answer, can you help me?

Comment: @CasellaJr feel free to ask questions on telegram with @ eamirgh id.